# PyAutoGui running slow

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm creating a bot to help me with a certain task. It retrieves data from a spreadsheet, turns it into a list and then it feeds a for loop with my actions.

However despite trying multiple ways to speed up the task, theres still a delay of about 3-5 seconds betweeen each action (click/type).

My function is the following:

```
def fat(wagon_number, wagon_weight):
    pyautogui.doubleClick(-1365, 361)
    pyautogui.write(wagon_number)
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 3.0
    pyautogui.click(-1020, 360)
    pyautogui.click(-891, 375)
    pyautogui.write(wagon_weight)
    pyautogui.click(-973, 472)
    pyautogui.click(-872, 342)
    pyautogui.write('1')
    pyautogui.click(-826, 338)
    pyautogui.write('1')
    pyautogui.click(-700, 342)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    pyautogui.click(-619, 343)
    pyautogui.write(wagon_weight)
    pyautogui.click(-541, 343)
    pyautogui.write(wagon_weight)
    pyautogui.click(-840, 388)
    pyautogui.write('1')
    pyautogui.click(-760, 388)
    pyautogui.write('1')
    pyautogui.click(-686, 388)
    pyautogui.write('123544')
    pyautogui.click(-743, 757)
    pyautogui.click(-766, 675)
```

This function is called by the following code:

```
#data retrieve
file_location = 'my file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(fr'{file_location}', dtype={'Name': str, 'Value': str})
wagon_list = df['Wagon'].tolist()
weight_list = df['Weight'].tolist()

for i in range(0, 10): #my range range is set based on the list lenght but I lost this part
    wagon = str(wagon_list[counter_0])
    weight = str(weight_list[counter_0])
    fat(wagon, weight)
    counter_0 += 1
    choice = input("Do you wanna continue? Type "y" or "n": \n")
    if choice == "n":
        break
    else:
        continue
```

How can I speed up the time between each mouse movement+click?

Comment: uhh, you set `pyautogui.PAUSE` to `3`...

Comment: Well, thats why I consider myself a begginer in python.
I meant "wait for 3s" but now its clear that pause is set to 3s rather than wait for 3s. I ended importing time, sleeping for 3s and thats it.

Big thanks my friend!

Answer (score 2):

Like Matiiss said, using pyautogui.pause(3), it sets the time between actions as 3s rather than pausing the code for 3s (thats what I meant).